# Using Memcache for storing connection objects

Tags: sql, connection, memcached, connection-pooling

Is it advisable to store SQL Connection objects in memcache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not store a connection object in any type of cache. With connection pooling opening a connection is very quick, so there is no need to cache it.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP this isn't even possible. If you try and serialize a database connection handler or a file handler you're in for a surprise.

```
$f = fopen('handler-serialize.php', 'r');
var_dump(serialize($f));
fclose($f);
```

The output of this would be:

```
string 'i:0;' (length=4)
```

I don't know how this is handled in other languages, but I would presume that all languages do not allow you to store handlers to resources that might not exist anymore when the stored values are woken up at a later date.

So to answer you question, **no** it is not advisable to store Connection objects in memcached.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize you're asking if you can cache a connection behind a connection?

Caching:
connect to memcached, fetch connection

No caching:
connect to database

You can't get around a connection, so I really don't see why you would want to do this.